# JavaFX - DnD - Third-Party Program to JavaFX App

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX app drag n drop email feature which is working fine if you drag a file from your windows explorer tab to the app.

However, if you try to drag an email file from your outlook into my app, the dragBoard hasFiles method is false, the OnDragDropped handler is executed, tho.

Im using the TransferMode.ANY and I as said, if you drag an email, or even txt files using Windows Explorer it will work.

Is there any trick or limitation if u want to drag from another app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, look what's in the DragBoard:

```
Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
db.getContentTypes().forEach(df -> System.out.println(df + " - " + db.getContent(df)));
```

You get an output like this:
[text/x-moz-url] - i
[application/x-moz-file-promise] - null
[text/x-moz-message] - i
[application/x-moz-file-promise-url] - java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=200 cap=200]
[_NETSCAPE_URL] - java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=63 cap=63]
(In this example I dragged a mail from FossaMail)

This tells you the mime-type (application/x-moz-file-promise-url) and the class (HeapByteBuffer):

```
DataFormat df = DataFormat.lookupMimeType("application/x-moz-file-promise-url");
ByteBuffer buffer = (ByteBuffer) db.getContent(df);
```